# How to make "Record My Desktop" capture only one monitor?

Tags: multiple-monitors, screencast, recordmydesktop

I've been using [Record My Desktop](http://recordmydesktop.sourceforge.net/about.php) for a while but a "problem" shows up. Today I have two monitors. One monitor extend another, but RMD when is capturing my desktop, records the **entire desktop** which means the capture of both monitors.

Is there a way to record only one monitor with Record My Desktop? If this is not possible, what software can I use to capture only one monitor (desktop), main one for example?

Just for comparison, on Windows there is a software called [Open Broadcaster Software (OBS)](https://obsproject.com/) wich have the options to separate the capture. I know they are working on a [multiplatform software (OBS Studio)](https://github.com/jp9000/obs-studio). But for now, it's not avaliable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [Record My Desktop](http://recordmydesktop.sourceforge.net/rug/p1_2b.php) website, you can apparently select a window to record, an area of the screen to record, or the entire desktop.  For what you are trying to do, I would set an area to record equal to the one monitor that you want to record.

Comment: Just one more info. After installed Record My Desktop, I needed to install the GUI for Record My Desktop. The package is gtk-recordmydesktop `sudo apt-get install gtk-recordmydesktop`. Tks!