# Screencasts - Record only one screen

Tags: screencast, desktop-recording

According to:
https://help.gnome.org/users/gnome-help/stable/screen-shot-record.html.en

We can record our screens using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, works very well. But I have 2 screens or monitors. When recording, the software captures both screens, but I only need to capture one.

How can I record only one screen?

Comment: See this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/493879/how-to-make-record-my-desktop-capture-only-one-monitor

Comment: A workaround for the built-in gnome "screencast" is to temporarily switch to single-display mode (via ubuntu display settings). Quite inconvenient, but at least this way you don't need to install any third-party screen recorders.

Answer (score 6):

Install **Kazam**, it's a great tool to record single/multiple screens 
Install Kazam in Ubuntu

```
sudo apt install kazam
```

If you want to install the newer Kazam 1.5.3, you can use unofficial PPA that is available for Ubuntu 18.04 and 16.04:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:sylvain-pineau/kazam
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt install kazam
```

You also need to install a few libraries in order to record the mouse clicks and keyboard presses.

```
sudo apt install python3-cairo python3-xlib
```

Source [here](https://itsfoss.com/kazam-screen-recorder/)

Comment: This can record one screen/all screens/one window/some area. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can simply temporary turn off second screen.